# GCP (Google Cloud) Kubernetes Pod Opeartors (that run DBT models) Error when upgrading Cloud Composer Environment despite same IAM policies

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, dbt

I recently upgraded our GCP cloud composer environment that has DAGs that uses Kubernetes Pods to run DBT models that transform BQ from:

`composer-2.0.28-airflow-2.2.5` (Image 1)

to:

`composer-2.1.11-airflow-2.4.3` (Image 2)

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions) is the list of available cloud images and their descriptions/packages.

When I first provisioned the upgraded environment I had to modify the Kubernetes configurations in the DBT DAGS to change the "resources" parameter to a "container_resources" parameters as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#airflow-2) documentation.

But then I try to run the DBT DAGS, which uses Kubernetes Pods, and I get this error below in all the DBT DAGS. I already have a namespace, and a workload identity with proper IAM permissions referenced as a parameter in the Kubernetes Pod.

I believe I found a good direction to fixing this because also in [this](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#version-5-0-0) documentation there states that:

> "Important: Adjustments in DAGs using KubernetesPodOperator will be
> required if you are upgrading from Composer version using 4.4.0 or
> earlier version of the provider to 5.0.0"

And I realized that Image 1 uses version 3.0.0 and Image 2 uses version 5.2.0 of that provider package. It also happens that cncf is in the header of the first line of the error message. So I looked and it says I have to add parameters called `config_file` & `kubernetes_conn_id` to migrate to the new version of the package. However, most of the information online I can find regarding these parameters relates to Kubernetes clusters, not Pods.

Has anyone else ran into this issue, what did you do to fix it? Can anyone explain the purpose of these `config_file` & `kubernetes_conn_id` parameters in relation to Pods running on the GCP environment? If I add the `config_file` in the Kubernetes pod operator, then am I only applying it to the Pods that reference it and not the whole cluster? What about the `kubernetes_conn_id`, how do I set this up or should I just use the kubernetes_default value?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 715, in patch_already_checked
    name=pod.metadata.name,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'metadata'
[XXXX-XX-XX, XX:XX:XX UTC] {kubernetes_pod.py:872} ERROR - (403)
Reason: Forbidden
```

Comment: Update: Added paremeters with values to KubernetesPodOperator("config_file":"/home/airflow/composer_kube_config",
"kubernetes_conn_id":"kubernetes_default",...) and then it started working again. I am still unsure of what, why, or how. But thats the fix if anyone comes up on the same thing.